# Performance of IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i needed to write a dynamic query on the customer database for obtaining few fields of a customer.

following is the code

```
[Route("api/getBasicCustList/{argType}/{argValue}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]

        public dynamic getCustomerDataUsername(String argType, String argValue)
        {
            IQueryable<CustomerDTO> query =
               (from recordset in db.Customers
                     select new CustomerDTO
                               {
                                   companyId = recordset.Company.Id,
                                   contactNum = recordset.ContactNum,
                                   username = recordset.UserName,
                                   emailAddress = recordset.Email,
                                   fullName = recordset.FullName,
                                   accountNumber = recordset.RCustId
                               }
                );

            switch (argType)
            {
                case "username" :
                    query = query.Where(c => c.username.StartsWith(argValue));
                    break;
                case "contactnum":
                    long mobNum = Int64.Parse(argValue);
                    query = query.Where(c => c.contactNum == mobNum);
                    break;
                case "fullname":
                    query = query.Where(c => c.fullName.Contains(argValue));
                    break;
            }

            return new { data = query.ToList() };
        }
```

this works fine and is solving my purpose.

my question here is when i write my first part of the `query` to get *all* the customer records and later on apply the where condition dynamically will the results be brought in memory or the complete query is generated and executed at db in one shot?

Since i have just 500 records as of now, i am not able to find any performance lag but when i take this to production i will be dealing with at least 200,000 to 300,000 records.

Comment: The query won't be executed until you reach that "ToList" at the end of your method.

Comment: oh Good.!! Can you or anyone else please provide a link from msdn or any online article which confirms this. thank you.

Comment: Here you go [Query Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @LakshmanPilaka maybe you add some words to your comment and add it as answer

Comment: You can always use some profiler or Database.Log to see how the queries are performed. Then you will see that query will executed after ToList invoke. More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: This really boils down to database performance. What database you use and what indexes you're using. Suggesting you're using SQL Server without full text index I would avoid using LIKE-queries (when using `.Where(c => c.fullName.Contains(argValue))`). However, it's all depends on how much data there are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, the answer is

> The query won't be executed until you reach that "ToList" at the end
>   of your method

from the MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx) shared by @GeorgPatscheider its mentioned

> At what point query expressions are executed can vary. LINQ queries
>   are always executed when the query variable is iterated over, not when
>   the query variable is created. This is called deferred execution
>
> *Deferred execution* enables multiple queries to be combined or a query
>   to be extended. When a query is extended, it is modified to include
>   the new operations, and the eventual execution will reflect the
>   changes.

Its also written that if queries have any of `Average`, `Count`, `First`, or `Max` it will perform an *immediate execution*.

thanks.

Comment: Query performance is still subject to Sql's - eg remember to index all the filtered columns in the case predicates.  For sanity, you might want to standardise on either Linq's Query Syntax or the lambda syntax ... You've combined both.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest factor in improving performance of the query against large tables is doing the filtering on the server (database) side. In Entity Framework 6.x and earlier, a query would fail to compile if EF could not convert the entire query to SQL. In EF Core, this is no longer the case. Instead as much of the query as possible will be converted to SQL. The rest will be evaluated on the client side.

All three of your filtering lambda expressions can be converted to SQL. However, if you were to write a predicate that can't be converted, then on EF Core your performance would suffer. All the records in the Customers table would be sent to the client for filtering despite the fact that the evaluation of the query is still deferred until `ToList()` is called. Your logs would [contain a warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation-logging) but that is easy to miss.

A good reference for this is Jon Smiths article [Entity Framework Core: Client vs. Server evaluation](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/entity-framework-core-client-vs-server-evaluation/).